# authentication and session in Java

Tags: java, authentication, session

I would like to know if it is possible to maintain an authentication (like a session with login and password in php) on a website from a java program, and if anyone had any lead on the subject or some reading for me, that would be great.

thanks

Comment: what is "a website from a java program" ?
are you speaking of a web-application in Java ? (Servlet/JSP)?

Comment: @leonboy, read the whole sentence. He's speaking of a java program that authenticates and creates a session with a php website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/tutorial.html) class. Once you have [authenticated](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/authentication.html) with the website the server will send you a cookie that you have to send with each successive request in order for the server to think that you are logged in.

Answer (score 4):

all you need is cookies, and java URLConnection. I use this all the time http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0092.html

you use readcookies after you open a new urlconnection and writecookies when creating a new one.